# Material card with align_parent_bottom overlaps navigation buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

So the issue i have is that on Samsung devices and on the Emulator on API 25, my material card is only shown in half, somehow overlapping the navigation buttons.
It is aligned using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

But when i tap on the edit text and the soft keyboard shows, the card is shown properly on top of it, and after closing the keyboard everything is shown properly.

The thing is... this doesn't happen on every device or even on the emulator on a greater API.
I will attach the xml code and some links to the screenshots since i don't have enough reputation to have pictures embedded.

[First image with the issue in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Manhl.jpg)

[With keyboard shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe60R.png)

[After keyboard is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8cYY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with the layout file, it happened purely because i had a postPoneEnterTransition() in the fragment. After i deleted it, the problem was fixed.